# Looping Session total point

Tags: php

i am using session to pass value to next page , it was successful problem is i got 25 question to do so , so i am thinking using loop to pass all the question and i didt get it work how i going to do so ?

html

```
<html>

<head>
</head> 

<form method="post" action="data.php">
<table>
<tr>
                <td><label> I am a high achiever. </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 11 -->  
<tr>
                <td><label> I am strong willed. </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 15 -->
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Score my test"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
   </html>
```

php

```
<?php
 // i need to add a loop here i++ but i didt get it to work i got 25 question 
session_start();

$_SESSION['D1'] = $_POST['D1'];
$_SESSION['D2'] = $_POST['D2'];

$Dpoint = $_SESSION['D1'] + $_SESSION['D2'];

?>

<html>

<body>
    <p><?php echo("{$Dpoint}"."<br />");?></p>
</body>

</html>
```

problem is i got D25 question to add total point i dont wanted to do it each by each do any one know how to loop session on php ? like something i < 25; i++ , i didt get it to work on. i dont wanted to plus the point each by each session. need help.

Comment: `for($i=1;$i<=25;$i++){$Dpoint += $_SESSION['D'.$i];}`

Comment: it didt work but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You better make input names as array: `<input type="text" name="question[]">` or `question[1]`, `question[2]`...
Than when submitted, use `for`/`foreach` loop to get all values:

```
$questions = !empty($_POST['question']) ? $_POST['question'] : false;
$total = 0;

if ($questions) {
    foreach ($questions as $i => $question) {
        $total += intval($question);
        //Additional if needed variables in session:
        $_SESSION['question'][$i] = intval($question);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this is the best way i can use it for now thank you , you did me a big favor~

Comment: i learned so much one more question isit the best way to do quiz php page using this Technic ?

Comment: @CherryLee I think yes. I usually use this structure when user is able to add more fields, than it's very simple to post-process them, no need to change any PHP code.

Comment: thank you i found it useful also , appreciate your help thank you.

Answer (score -1):

try the below code

```
<tr>
                <td><label> I am a high achiever. </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="points[D1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="points[D1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="points[D1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
            </tr><!-- 11 -->  
<tr>
                <td><label> I am strong willed. </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="points[D2]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="points[D2]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="3"> 3 </td>
            </tr><!-- 15 -->
<tr>
```

in PHP

```
  $Dpoint = 0;
    for($i=1;$<=count($_POST['points']);$i++){
      $_SESSION["D$i"] = $_POST["D$i"];
       $Dpoint += $_SESSION["D$i"];
    }
```

or you can do like

```
 <tr>
                    <td><label> I am a high achiever. </label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="2"> 2 </td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="D1" value="3"> 3 </td>
                </tr><!-- 11 -->  
    <tr>
                    <td><label> I am strong willed. </label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="1"> 1 </td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="2"> 2 </td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="D2" value="3"> 3 </td>
                </tr><!-- 15 -->
    <tr>
```

In PHP

```
$_SESSION['points']['D1'] = $_POST['D1'];
$_SESSION['points']['D2'] = $_POST['D2'];
$Dpoint = 0;
for($i=1;$<=count($_SESSION['points']);$i++){
       $Dpoint += $_SESSION['points']["D$i"];
    }
```

Comment: need to change your `['D$i']` to `["D$i"]` as php does not parse variables inside single quotes

Comment: @sean ok great miss that one

Comment: I think it will throw error, because there is no such constant as `points`. `+= $_SESSION['points']["D{$i}"];`

Comment: hmm i think you are right something is wrong with the point there

Comment: in the last one for loop I missed $i check it